# How to check string contains html tags most generic way

Tags: html, regex, string, xcode, swift3

How can I check that if string contains HTML tags or not?

For Example :

```
"<li>JSON syntax is derived from JavaScript object</li><li>"
```

Comment: This is not very clear. What exactly are you trying to match?

Answer (score 4):

Try using regex

```
 private func isHtml(_ value:String) -> Bool {

        let validateTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", "<[a-z][\\s\\S]*>")
        return validateTest.evaluate(with: value)
    }
```

You can test regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/OnxacD/1)

Answer (score 1):

This regex checks any proper HTML or XML tags.

```
private func isHtml(_ value:String) -> Bool {
    let validateTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", "<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\\1>")
    return validateTest.evaluate(with: value)
}
```

Example:

```
isHtml("<ol><li>JSON syntax is derived from JavaScript</li></ol>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL) isHTMLValue {
    NSString *htmlRegex = @"<[a-z][\\s\\S]*>";
    NSPredicate *htmlText = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", htmlRegex];
    return [htmlText evaluateWithObject:self];
}
```